# Return second value from multiple arrays Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I return the first values from a set of arrays?

```
var arr = [
    ['2009', 1000, 400, 800],
    ['2010', 1170, 460, 1200],
    ['2011', 660, 1120, 500],
    ['2012', 1030, 540, 800]
], res, i, a, b, c, d, e;

!function doMerge() {
    for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        res = arr[i];       
        console.log(res.splice(1));
    }    
}(arr)

// get rid of years
// prints    
[1000, 400, 800] 
[1170, 460, 1200] 
[660, 1120, 500] 
[1030, 540, 800]
```

I'm trying to build an array of the first of these values `[1000, 1170, 660, 1030]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
res = [];

function doMerge() {
    for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        res.push(arr[i][1]);       
    }    
}

doMerge();

console.log(res);
```

outputs `[ 1000, 1170, 660, 1030 ]`

Comment: Where is `[1000, 1170, 660, 1030]` produced by this?

Comment: it is in the res variable;  this was the minimal change from original code.  I would have returned the new array from the function.

Comment: You have a syntax error on line 3 (an unmatched `{`) and even after fixing, I don't think `res` becomes what you think it becomes (try it and see)

Comment: remove console.log with splice, I missed that.

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr = [
    ['2009', 1000, 400, 800],
    ['2010', 1170, 460, 1200],
    ['2011', 660, 1120, 500],
    ['2012', 1030, 540, 800]
];

var newArr = [];

for (var x = 0; x < arr.length; x++){
  newArr.push(arr[x][1]);
}

console.log(newArr);
```

Here is a solution.

http://jsfiddle.net/wcVZH/

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want a `for` or `while` loop you can one line this with [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
var myArr = arr.map(function (a) {return a[1];});
```